# Javascript live search not responding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

Trying to create a live search using javascript and it seems as if the script is not responding. I have the script within a .js file and I have added it at the end of the page.

The functionality I want is when the user types into `#PokemonSearch` it will hid irrelevant `pokemon-selector-item` divs

What happens when I type into `#PokemonSearch` with the following code? Absolutely nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#PokemonSearch").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".pokemon-selector-item").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).attr(".pokemon-name").text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
        }
    });

  });

});
```

HTML Selector item example:

```
                            <div class="pokemon-selector-item">
                                <img class="pokemon-image" src="~/assets/images/pokemon/pokemon-50x50/charmander.png" />
                                <div class="pokemon-selector-info">
                                    <span class="pokemon-name">Charmander</span>
                                    <span class="pokemon-type">Fire Pokemon</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: `.attr(".pokemon-name").text()` doesn't make sense. If that's actually what you have, you failed to open your console, read the error message, and provide it here.

Comment: @KevinB I apologise I'm quite new to javascript, thank you though I forgot about the debugging tools!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo.  `.attr(".pokemon-name")` on line 11 should be `.find(".pokemon-name")`